# Binding a WPF ShortCut Key to a Command in the ViewModel

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, shortcut

I have a WPF app that is using the MVVM pattern. Hooking up buttons to the VM is pretty straight forward since they implement the ICommand. I have a context menu that works similar. The next step is to create shortcut keys for the context menu. I can't figure out how to get the shortcut key invoke the Command. Here is an example:

```
<MenuItem Header="Update" Command="{Binding btnUpdate}" >
    <MenuItem.Icon>
        <Image Source="/Images/Update.png"
               Width="16"
               Height="16" />
        </MenuItem.Icon>
    </MenuItem>
```

now I've added this:

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="U"
                Modifiers="Control" 
                Command="{Binding btnUpdate}" />
</Window.InputBindings>
```

to try and connect the shortcut keys to the same binding, but this doesn't work. The error is:

> Error  169 A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Command' property of type 'KeyBinding'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.

Isn't there a way to hook up this event to the Command? I can't figure this out.

thanks in advance!

Bill

Comment: I should mention that I am using Josh Smith's RelayCommand as well.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I wrote a [custom markup extension](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2009/03/17/wpf-using-inputbindings-with-the-mvvm-pattern/) to "bind" `InputBindings` to commands, which can be used almost like a real binding :

```
<UserControl.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Modifiers="Control" 
                Key="E" 
                Command="{input:CommandBinding EditCommand}"/>
</UserControl.InputBindings>
```

Note that this markup extension uses private reflection, so it can only be used if your application runs in full trust...

Another option is to use the `CommandReference` class. It can be found in the MVVM toolkit available [here](http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/14962). It's probably a cleaner approach, but a bit more complex to use.

Note that in WPF 4, the `InputBinding.Command`, `InputBinding.CommandParameter` and `InputBinding.CommandTarget` properties are dependency properties, so they can be bound normally

Comment: I followed the exs in the WPF MVVM Docs - great examples! Exactly what I want to do. Unfortunately, the context menu items work fine, but the shortcut keys do nothing. I can't even figure out to debug this since nothing happens when I press the shortcut keys.

Comment: Could it be that I am trying to use these on shortcut keys on a ContextMenu instead of a standard menu?

Comment: which technique did you use ? the markup extension or the CommandReference class ?

Comment: The CommandReference - it does seem to matter where in the XAML I put the KeyBinding. If I put it in the DataGrid that is in the window I do hit the breakpoint in the CanExecute - but it seems to always return false.

Comment: I was thinking that if I put the KeyBinding anywhere in the window that it would work but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: the KeyBinding is triggered when the control on which it's defined is focused... perhaps that's why it doesn't work for you ?

Comment: That's possible. I would have thought that if the KeyBinding was put on the window which has the controls on it, that it would be triggered by the child controls as well, but maybe not?

Comment: Finally got it to work. It was just getting the KeyBindings and CommandReferences in the right places. Not just inside the window but inside the first grid.

Answer (score 43):

The following code can be used to bind a shortcut key directly to a command:

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Path=NameOfYourCommand}" 
                Key="O" 
                Modifiers="Control"/>
</Window.InputBindings>
```

Add this after Window.Resources in the XAML code of your view.

Comment: Yeah not sure what OP's problem was, but this works fine. (I'm using MVVM light)

Comment: He specifically said this didn't work, and the selected answer explains why: He's not using WPF4.  Not sure why you post his exact code as an "answer"

Comment: is the `Modifiers` `Ctrl`?

Comment: @aaronburro OK answers and the question should be updated to mention WPF 4, but for those of us who even don't look at the question this answer is useful, and to be honest if I  read the question I would be confused.

Answer (score 9):

I agree that doing it in XAML is ideal, but for completeness sake, you could also add your binding in code.  If you do it in the constructor, just make sure it is after the call to `InitializeComponent()`

```
InputBindings.Add(new KeyBinding(btnUpdate, new KeyGesture(Key.U, ModifierKeys.Control));
```

Comment: +1 This method allowed me to put it into my View because I needed the function to only work with UI elements.

Comment: But this binds a button control, `btnUpdate` to the shortcut key Ctrl-U, not a to a command like Michel Keijzers's XAML does.

Comment: I was answering the original post which was trying to bind to something called "btnUpdate".

Comment: This works, but you have to replace btnUpdate with yourButton.Command.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach for binding a WPF Shortcut Key to a Command property of the ViewModel is shown in the ShortcutKey sample of the [**WPF Application Framework (WAF)**](http://waf.codeplex.com) project.

Comment: Thanks ... I will need some time to look into it (meaning I don't have much time now but I upvoted because the link seems very useful (not only because of my question only).

Comment: This answer is only for propaganda, it doesn't give any help, neither does the given link

Answer (score 0):

Have been able to add Keybinding on the DataGrid level. Like this :

Xaml :

```
<DataGrid 
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding YourCollection}"                         
                    CanUserAddRows="False"                        
                    HeadersVisibility="Column" 
                    CanUserDeleteRows="False" 
                    CanUserSortColumns="True"
                    CanUserResizeRows="False"
                    CanUserResizeColumns="False"                       
                    SelectedItem="{Binding YourSelectedItem}" 
                    SelectionMode="Single" 
                    SelectionUnit="FullRow"
                   >
                <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu>
                       **<MenuItem Header="Delete" InputGestureText="Del" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}">**
                        </MenuItem>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                **<DataGrid.InputBindings>
                    <KeyBinding Key="Delete" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" CommandParameter="Delete"/>**
                </DataGrid.InputBindings>
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column Header" Binding="{Binding YourColumn}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

View Model :

```
public ICommand DeleteCommand
            {
                get
                {
                    return new DelegateCommand(ExecuteCommand, CanExecute);
                }
            }

  private void ExecuteCommand()
{
// your code to delete here.
   YourCollection.Remove(YourSelectedItem);
}

private void CanExecute()
{
// logic to check if the delete command can execute.
   return YourSelectedItem != null ;
}
```