# Assign a shortcut key to a command in a ViewModel in WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Binding a WPF ShortCut Key to a Command in the ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382916/binding-a-wpf-shortcut-key-to-a-command-in-the-viewmodel)

On a WPF window I have a menu-item that is bound to a command in the ViewModel:

```
<MenuItem Header="_Edit page" Command="{Binding EditCommand}"/>
```

The command is a [RelayCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090030) which forwards the command to a method:

```
EditCommand = new RelayCommand(() => editPage());
```

I want to assign a shortcut key Ctrl+E to the command.

How should I do this?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382916/binding-a-wpf-shortcut-key-to-a-command-in-the-viewmodel

Comment: Ok, thanks. This question is a duplicate.

Comment: If you are using .Net 4.0 - you can bind directly without using the attached behaviour mentioned in that (his actual example will work in 4.0 but not 3.5).

Answer (score 0):

The **ShortcutKey** sample application of the **[WPF Application Framework (WAF)](http://waf.codeplex.com)** shows how to implement this scenario. You will find two versions of this download:

1. .NET 3.5 - uses some lines of code behind.
2. .NET 4 - Uses Binding.