# Help on using short cut keys

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a WPF user control where I have multiple text boxes and and combo boxes. For easy use I want to provide shortcut keys to focus some main control.

Suppose if I press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> it will focus on a text box named `txtPatient`.
If I press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> it will focus on a text box named `txtRef`.

I am using MVVM as the design pattern.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds to me like basic accessibility (mnemonics), which is easy to obtain by adding labels to your controls like:

```
<Label Content="_Name" Target="{Binding ElementName=textBoxName}" />
<TextBox x:Name="textBoxName" />
```

Notice the "_N" - that means when the user presses <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>, `textBoxName` will get focus.

Answer (score 1):

Thomas Levesque answered this is a separate post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382916/binding-a-wpf-shortcut-key-to-a-command-in-the-viewmodel).

He mentions his own custom markup extension which allows for just this:

```
<UserControl.InputBindings>
<KeyBinding Modifiers="Control" Key="E" Command="{input:CommandBinding EditCommand}"/>
</UserControl.InputBindings>
```

Hope this helps :)