# I need help with the design for many keyboard shortcuts assosciated with various methods

Tags: .net, wpf, c#-4.0, wpf-controls, prism

I have a requirement to come up with many keyboard shortcuts and assosciate them with various methods. I need help on design in C#. Any specific dstrucs to use?

Answer (score 0):

Start with [ApplicationCommands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.applicationcommands.aspx) and then looking into the generic [commanding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382916/binding-a-wpf-shortcut-key-to-a-command-in-the-viewmodel) constructs.