# Trying to use (System-Wide) Hotkeys in WPF/C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I've been trying to use System-Wide/Global HotKeys in my latest WPF/C# project. Lucky for me, I came upon this wonderful class, here - http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/274003/Global-Hotkeys-in-WPF.

The only problem is, *I can't get it to work*. I've been banging my head with this since last week, and the weird thing is, I'm getting no errors. Here's my code, any ideas why?

```
HotKey hotkey = new HotKey((System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource)System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.FromVisual(App.Current.MainWindow));
                //hotkey.Modifiers = list[i]._HotkeyA.Modifier; hotkey.Key = list[i]._HotkeyA._Key;
                hotkey.Modifiers = HotKey.ModifierKeys.Shift; hotkey.Key = Key.F2;
                hotkey.HotKeyPressed += new EventHandler<HotKeyEventArgs>(delegate(Object o, HotKeyEventArgs e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Congratulations, Cap'n.");
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("YAAY HOTKEY HAZ BEEN TEH PRESSEDS!");
                });
                hotkey.Enabled = true;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've use a Command and binding approach, one example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382916/binding-a-wpf-shortcut-key-to-a-command-in-the-viewmodel

Comment: Thanks, but I mean system-wide hotkeys.

Comment: do you use System.Windows.Input.Key.F2 or its WindowsForms "brother"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following implementation Uses the WPF ComponentDispatcher class to Dispatch Windows Messages.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Interop;

[Flags]
public enum ModifierKeyCodes : uint
{
    Alt = 1,
    Control = 2,
    Shift = 4,
    Windows = 8
}

/// <summary>
/// Virtual Key Codes
/// </summary>
public enum VirtualKeyCodes : uint
{
A = 65,
B = 66,
C = 67,
D = 68,
E = 69,
F = 70,
G = 71,
H = 72,
I = 73,
J = 74,
K = 75,
L = 76,
M = 77,
N = 78,
O = 79,
P = 80,
Q = 81,
R = 82,
S = 83,
T = 84,
U = 85,
V = 86,
W = 87,
X = 88,
Y = 89,
Z = 90
}

class KeyboardHook : IDisposable
{
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, ModifierKeyCodes fdModifiers, VirtualKeyCodes vk);

#region Fields
WindowInteropHelper host;
bool IsDisposed = false;
int Identifier;

public Window Window { get; private set; }

public VirtualKeyCodes Key { get; private set; }

public ModifierKeyCodes Modifiers { get; private set; }
#endregion

public KeyboardHook(Window Window, VirtualKeyCodes Key, ModifierKeyCodes Modifiers)
{
    this.Key = Key;
    this.Modifiers = Modifiers;

    this.Window = Window;
    host = new WindowInteropHelper(Window);

    Identifier = Window.GetHashCode();

    RegisterHotKey(host.Handle, Identifier, Modifiers, Key);

    ComponentDispatcher.ThreadPreprocessMessage += ProcessMessage;
}

void ProcessMessage(ref MSG msg, ref bool handled)
{
    if ((msg.message == 786) && (msg.wParam.ToInt32() == Identifier) && (Triggered != null))
        Triggered();
}

public event Action Triggered;

public void Dispose()
{
    if (!IsDisposed)
    {
        ComponentDispatcher.ThreadPreprocessMessage -= ProcessMessage;

        UnregisterHotKey(host.Handle, Identifier);
        Window = null;
        host = null;
    }
    IsDisposed = true;
}
}
```

Disposing the Object Unregisters the HotKey.
You need to hold a reference to the KeyboardHook class to prevent it from being unregistered.

Example:

```
// Registers a Hook to MyWindow - Ctrl+A and calls DoWork() when Triggered.
var KH = new KeyboardHook(MyWindow, VirtualKeyCodes.A, ModifierKeyCodes.Ctrl);
KH += () => DoWork();

// When you don't need the Hook
KH.Dispose();
```

Comment: Nice! I haven't worked with C# in awhile, but this looks handy.

Comment: @un-lucky Not sure. Done.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are holding a strong reference to that HotKey. From the link you provided that object has a finalizer that would set the Enabled to false which would unregister the hotkey.

Comment: Note if that's not the issue then please post a more complete snippet of the usage - i.e. where you are creating the hotkey, etc.