# How to hook up an Undo Command that lives in the ViewModel to be called by Ctrl-Z?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, .net-4.0, command, wpf-4.0

I implemented my own Undo/Redo functionality (with a lot of help from the web) which was enlightening. The Undo and Redo commands are defined in the ViewModel. I am able to hook these commands up through the `Command` property of a `MenuItem`. As a final step I want to hook these commands up through the standard CTRL-Z and CTRL-Y keyboard shortcuts.

To my dismay I found out that the `MenuItem` class does not support this. Using WinForms this would have been a snap, but it seems that achieving this in WPF is quite involved.  How is it most easily done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question is in fact a duplicate question of [this one:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382916/binding-a-wpf-shortcut-key-to-a-command-in-the-viewmodel)
 *However*: as of WPF 4.0 Michel Keijzer's answer is the correct one, very easy! I will put it here (before the question gets closed :-))

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Path=UndoCommand}" 
      Key="Z" Modifiers="Control"></KeyBinding>
</Window.InputBindings>
```

Add this after Window.Resources